# Why would anyone want to use GCE Persistent Disk or EBS with Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes

These disks are accessible by only a single node.

Each node would have different data.

Also, any node can be terminated at any time, so you  would have to find a way to reattach the volume to a new node that replaces the old one. How would you do that?

And after scaleup, a new node might not have one of these disks available to attach to, so you would need a new disk.

And why might anyone want to do all this? Just for   temporary space? For that, they could use an  EC2 instance store or GCE boot disk (though I guess that that might be enough.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm specifically familiar with EBS; I assume GCE persistent disks work the same way.  The important detail is that an EBS volume is not tied to a specific node; while it can only be attached to one node at a time, it can be moved to another node, and Kubernetes knows how to do this.

An EBS volume can be dynamically attached to an EC2 instance.  In Kubernetes, generally there is a *dynamic volume provisioner* that's able to create PersistentVolume objects that are backed by EBS volumes in response to PersistentVolumeClaim objects.  Critically, if a Pod uses a PVC that references an EBS-volume PV, the storage driver knows that, wherever the Pod is scheduled, it can dynamically attach the EBS volume to that EC2 instance.

That means that an EBS-volume PersistentVolume isn't actually "locked" to a single node.  If the Pod is deleted and a new one uses the PersistentVolumeClaim, the volume can "move" to the node that runs the new Pod.  If the Node is removed, all of its Pods can be rescheduled elsewhere, and the EBS volumes can go somewhere else too.

An EBS volume can only be attached to one instance at a time; in Kubernetes volume terminology, it can only have a `ReadWriteOnce` [access mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes).  If it could be attached to many instances (as, for instance, an EFS NFS-based filesystem could be) it could be `ReadOnlyMany` or `ReadWriteMany`.

This makes EBS be a reasonably good default choice for persistent data storage, *if your application actually needs it*.  It's not actually host-specific and it can move around the cluster as needed.  It won't work if two Pods need to share files, but this is generally a complex and fragile setup and it's better to design your application to not need it.

The best setup is if your application doesn't need persistent local storage at all.  This makes it easy to scale Deployments, because the data is "somewhere else".  The data could be in a database; the data could be in a managed database, such as RDS; or it could be in an object-storage system like S3.  Again, this requires changes in your application to not use local files for data storage.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that these disks, with their data, can be reattached to a new node. But what is the value of such persistence when different nodes' disks are not synchronized to each other and a new node (in upscaling) might get a new disk with no data?

Comment: It's not "different nodes' disks"; it is a separate disk that you can attach to a single instance at a time.  If the pod moves to a different node, the EBS volume will be detached from the existing node and reattached to the new node; it will be literally the same underlying storage.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that the disk  can be attached to one instance at a time, Let's say we have 3 such disks in a cluster with 3 nodes. These disks will not have the same data (unless they are read-only), yet a Kubernetes cluster is supposed to be designed with redundancy and so we'd want the disks to have the same data. If a 4th node is added, then certainly the nodes will be attached to disks with very different data. How can that work?

Comment: That gets to a little more application-level concern around how it maintains replicas on separate disks.  In Elasticsearch, for example, an index has some number of shards, and each shard has some number of replicas, which will be on distinct disks; if you add a disk it will have data copied on to it from one of the existing systems, and if you lose a disk, there should be another replica of it on another system.  This is not something Kubernetes handles on its own.

Comment: Thank you. So I see that the use cases are very specialized. Either a single-node persistent store, or   the application handles sharding, or it;'s just a scratch disk for temporary data